# Mounting Acoustic Foam in a rented flat

Tags: adhesive, silicone, rental, acoustic

I'm looking for a reversible way to mount my acoustic foam on the wall.

My current plan: using Sanitary Silicone from a cartridge.

This is in the hope that it would both stick easily and is relatively simple to remove in the future.

Is this a mistake? are there less damaging ways to do this?

Comment: depends on the weight of the foam and the type of wall.  .... you could use sewing pins with large heads like these if you have drywall ... https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX1472563.jpg .... they make very small holes that you can fill when you move out

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much weight this is, but if possible, I'd go with Command Adhesive strips. [For example.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FEJ3OA4) (These are pretty common; just check Walmart or similar.) These are basically perfectly designed to avoid damage to rentals, and removal is simple. Each strip holds 4lb, so a quick weigh should tell you how many you'll need per foam piece. If you're worried about them attaching to the actual foam, remember that you can use more permenant methods to attach the strip to the foam. (Needle and thread could even create a mechanical attachment.)

Answer (score 0):

I would shy away from caulk or silicone, unless you're really sure how it will react with the foam. (and the wall)

They make a bunch of double sided tapes and spray adhesive for acoustical foam from lite to "never gettin' it off". I've used these with good success in several studios I've designed and built over the years.

Here's a video I found of a guy mounting foam that might help... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIPXq0WAnpg

Cheers.

Comment: I think I might end up going with Velcro patches. likely easier to take off